# How to generate a list of names in random order with no repeats?

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to generate a list of names in random order with no repeats in cells E2 to E16. You can see the results below.
[image]

I want like this
[image]

```
Sub Button1_Click()
'Must be a dynamic array ie no range
Dim MyNames() As String
Dim strName As String
Dim Ichosen As Integer
'load list into Array based on split by /
'note will start as MyNums(0) and finish with MyNums(number-1)
MyNames = Split("John/Bill/Steve/Echo/Sandy/A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/J", "/")
Do
    Randomize
    'This will work with any length of name sequence
    Ichosen = Int(Rnd * (UBound(MyNames) + 1))
    strName = (MyNames(Ichosen))
    Range("E2:E16").Value = strName
    'move top num,ber into chosen slot
    MyNames(Ichosen) = MyNames(UBound(MyNames))
    If UBound(MyNames) > 0 Then
        'delete top number
        ReDim Preserve MyNames(0 To UBound(MyNames) - 1)
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. `Range("E2:E16").Value = strName` Whatever name you are creating, it's being assigned to **all** cells in range `E12:E16`, so they will be the same always. I think you need a diferent aproach and a dinamic destination range (probably a loop will do)

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns how to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've adapted your code. Try it:

```
Dim MyNames() As String
Dim strName As String
Dim Ichosen As Integer

Dim i As Long, TotalRandoms As Long
i = 2 'starting row

'load list into Array based on split by /
'note will start as MyNums(0) and finish with MyNums(number-1)
MyNames = Split("John/Bill/Steve/Echo/Sandy/A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/J", "/")
TotalRandoms = UBound(MyNames) + 2
Dim str As String

Do Until i > TotalRandoms

    Randomize
    'This will work with any length of name sequence
    Ichosen = Int(Rnd * (UBound(MyNames) + 1))
    strName = (MyNames(Ichosen))
    str = Join(MyNames, "/")
    If Right(str, Len(strName) + 1) = "/" & strName Then
        str = Replace(str, "/" & strName, "")  'we replace strname in last position of array
    Else
        str = Replace(str, strName & "/", "") 'we replace strname in any position of array (except last one)
    End If

    Range("E" & i).Value = strName
    Erase MyNames
    MyNames = Split(str, "/")
    i = i + 1
Loop

Erase MyNames
```

[image]

It's pretty similar to original from you, but I've changed the way your array gets rid of elements already used. Also, changed the way it assigns values to a cell, with a variable.

I've done some runs, and looks like everything it's ok. No duplicates and all of them.

Hope you can adapt this to your needs.